# Add item to a list of dictionaries if item is in different list python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

There is not a good way for me to explain it, but I can try my best to help visualize what I'm trying to do.

I have a list:

```py
post1_tags = ['Tag1', 'Tag2']
```

and I also have a similar list.

```py
post2_tags = ['Tag1']
```

Basically, if the first list has the tag, then add it to a dictionary of lists with the tag name as the key.
Because post1_tags has the tags `'Tag1'` and `'Tag2'`, it should be added to a dictionary like this:

```py
tags = {'Tag1': [post1_tags], 'Tag2': [post1_tags]}
```

but if was just `post2_tags`, then it should become:

```py
tags = {'Tag1': [post2_tags]}
```

I want to be able to put the lists together in a dictionary with they key being the tag, and if they have that tag, add it.

I want the end result to look something like this:

```py
tags = {'Tag1': [post1_tags, post2_tags], 'Tag2': [post_1_tags] }
```

I hope this makes sense. If not please tell me so I can clarify.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution for this already implemented in the basic python libraries. Have you tried implementing a solution for this problem yourself already? If so, what is your approach and what are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me wether you want the contents or the names of the lists in the dicts, but here's a solution:

```py
post1_tags = ['Tag1', 'Tag2']
post2_tags = ['Tag1']
tags = dict()

#Making the dictionary just out of the first list
for tag in post1_tags:
    tags[tag] = ["post1_tags"]

for tag in post2_tags:
    if tag in tags.keys():      #Checking if the tags are already in the dict
        tags[tag].append("post2_tags")
    else:    #Adding the remaining to the dict
        tags[tag] = ["post2_tags"]

print(tags)
```

Just remove the `"`s around the list names if you want their content.

You can also iterate over a list of the lists (like in the second for loop, but wrapped into another) if you don't need the variable names of the lists.

Comment: Thanks! This worked just the way I wanted it too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list1 = ["Tag1", "Tag2"]
list2 = ["Tag1"]
lists = {"list1": list1 , "list2": list2}
dictionary = {}
for key, value in lists.items():
    for tag in value:
        try:
            if dictionary[tag]:
               dictionary[tag] += f" {key}"
        except KeyError:
            dictionary[tag] = key
        
print(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the shortest method:

```py
tags = {}

for i in post1_tags + post2_tags:
    tags[i] = [n for n,v in filter(lambda t: isinstance(t[1],list) and t[0].startswith('post'), locals().items()) if i in v]

print(tags)
```

I feel like most of the code is explainable asides from line 4. What line 7 does is first get a list of every variable that has the specific tag in it and begins with `'post'`.

The only downside of this code is that is uses `local` variables. `local` and `global` variables are items that can mess up the code. If your code is short, then this is perfect. However, if your code is long, then I would advise putting the code into a function to keep it clean.